# A single view with two models in asp.net MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a class called movie.cs in the modal which is as follows.

```
namespace CodFirst.Models
{
    public class Movie
    {
        public int MovieId { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }

        public string genre { get; set; }
    }

    public class Student
    {

        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        public string fname { get; set; }
        public string lname { get; set; }
    }

}
```

And i have a context class in the same modal called moviecontext as:

```
namespace CodFirst.Models
{
    public class MovieContext:DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now i want to access the data of both Movies and student in the same view.But i am not able to access data of any one either.

IN the controller i have

```
 MovieContext db = new MovieContext();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //db.Movies.ToList();
        var myvar = db.Movies;

        return View(myvar);
    }
```

And finally the view is as follows:

```
 @model CodFirst.Models.MovieContext

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

@foreach(var item in Model.Movies)
{
  @Html.DisplayName("movie: ") @item.name;  @Html.DisplayName(" type: ") @item.genre;  <br />

}
```

Comment: How do you try to access both of them and where do you fail with which error? Have you tried searching for "ViewModels"?
Also: The model in your view, should be of type Movie, not MovieContext.

Comment: At first i am trying to access onyone..With @modal.projectname.Modals.movie i am able to access only data from movie but not from student.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is a ViewModel. A Viewmodel class consists of those classes you want to display in your case: Movies and Students. It can be used to only wrap those information you need or to be a wrapper for more complex data.

```
public class MovieStudentVM
{
    public IEnumerable<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

Your Index method should now return your Viewmodel:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var vm = new MovieStudentVM();
    vm.Movies = db.Movies;
    vm.Students = db.Students;

    return View(vm);
}
```

After this just build up your View:

```
@model CodFirst.Models.MovieStudentVM

@foreach(var item in Model.Movies)
{
  @Html.DisplayName("movie: ") @item.name;  @Html.DisplayName(" type: ") @item.genre;  <br />
}

@foreach(var item in Model.Students)
{
  @* ... *@
}
```

Further information:

- [What is ViewModel in MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc)

Comment: db u have used is from moviecontext class right.Please can you tell me the difference between viewmodal and context class.

Comment: The dbcontet class is responsible for the interaction with your data, which resides on your database. The ViewModel is just a blueprint on how the data looks like. Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj729737.aspx

Answer (score 2):

A good practice with this kind of stuff is using so called 'ViewModels'. Define a new model that holds your data that you want to access in your view:

MyViewModel:

```
public class MyViewModel {
    public IEnumerable<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new MyViewModel {
        Movies = db.Movies.ToList(),
        Students = db.Students.ToList()
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

Then the view:

```
@model CodFirst.Models.MyViewModel

// your view stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go with View Model but if you really wanna use Tuple here you go

```
public class ToupleController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var first = new FirstModel();
        var second = new SecondModel();

        return View(Tuple.Create(first,second));
    }
}
```

and in your view

```
    @model Tuple<FirstModel, SecondModel>
    <div> 
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Item1.Prop1)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Item1.Prop2)
    </div>
   // to access your second model
    <div> 
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Item2.Prop1)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Item2.Prop2)
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

its happening because you are expecting MovieContext in view and you are passing Movie model so try making viewmodel as shown in below code :-

```
 public class ViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

and view :-

```
 @model CodFirst.Models.ViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

@foreach(var item in Model.Movies)
{
  @Html.DisplayName("movie: ") @item.name;  @Html.DisplayName(" type: ") @item.genre;  <br />

}
```

Comment: I cant see the difference...its just i have the class name moviecontext and you have class name Viewmodal.Other than that whats the difference

Comment: Are you sure you want to build a ViewModel consisting of `DbSet<>`?

Comment: it was by mistake @Serv